# How do I show required attendees on the printed copy of meeting invites?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I print each meeting invite for my boss to take to meetings.  He likes to see who the organizer is and who the attendees are.  Now in Outlook 2013, when I print the meeting invite, it only shows the organizer name and not the required attendees and optional attendees.  Is there a function in Outlook 2013 I need to enable or change?

Answer (score 2):

#### when I print the meeting invite, it only shows the organizer name

> and not the required attendees and optional attendees.

Outlook only offers limited support for this. You can use the following workarounds.

---

#### Create a List of Meeting Attendees and Responses

> This code sample gets the appointment details and attendees (along with their responses) and inserts it into a new Outlook message form, which you can print, send or copy the data for use in other applications.
>
> [image: Get a list of meeting attendees]
>
> Tested in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010. It should work in Outlook 2000 and up. Note that the code will trigger the security prompt.
>
> Tested in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010. It should work in Outlook 2000 and up. Note that the code will trigger the security prompt.
>
> **Get Meeting Attendee List Macro**
>
> To use, open Outlook's VBA Editor by pressing Alt+F11. Right click on the Project1 in the left pane and choose Insert > Module. Copy this code and paste it into the Module.
>
> Get the GetCurrentItem function from [Outlook VBA: work with open item or selected item](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/) and paste it at the end of the module.
>
> Then select or open a meeting you organized and run the macro to create a message containing the meeting details. The total counts of accepted, declined, tentative, and no response is added to the list.

```
Sub GetAttendeeList()
 
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objAttendees As Outlook.Recipients
Dim objAttendeeReq As String
Dim objAttendeeOpt As String
Dim objOrganizer As String
Dim dtStart As Date
Dim dtEnd As Date
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strLocation As String
Dim strNotes As String
Dim strMeetStatus As String
Dim strCopyData As String
Dim strCount  as String 

On Error Resume Next
 
Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
Set objAttendees = objItem.Recipients
 
On Error GoTo EndClean:

' Is it an appointment
If objItem.Class <> 26 Then
  MsgBox "This code only works with meetings."
  GoTo EndClean:
End If
 
' Get the data
dtStart = objItem.Start
dtEnd = objItem.End
strSubject = objItem.Subject
strLocation = objItem.Location
strNotes = objItem.Body
objOrganizer = objItem.Organizer
objAttendeeReq = ""
objAttendeeOpt = ""
 
' Get The Attendee List
For x = 1 To objAttendees.Count
   strMeetStatus = ""
   Select Case objAttendees(x).MeetingResponseStatus
     Case 0
       strMeetStatus = "No Response (or Organizer)"
       ino = ino + 1
     Case 1
       strMeetStatus = "Organizer"
       ino = ino + 1
     Case 2
       strMeetStatus = "Tentative"
       it = it + 1
     Case 3
       strMeetStatus = "Accepted"
       ia = ia + 1
     Case 4
       strMeetStatus = "Declined"
       ide = ide + 1
   End Selec
  
   If objAttendees(x).Type = olRequired Then
      objAttendeeReq = objAttendeeReq & objAttendees(x).Name & vbTab & strMeetStatus & vbCrLf
   Else
      objAttendeeOpt = objAttendeeOpt & objAttendees(x).Name & vbTab & strMeetStatus & vbCrLf
   End If
Next
  
  
 strCopyData = "Organizer: " & objOrganizer & vbCrLf & "Subject:  " & strSubject & vbCrLf & _
  "Location: " & strLocation & vbCrLf & "Start:    " & dtStart & vbCrLf & "End:     " & dtEnd & _
  vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Required: " & vbCrLf & objAttendeeReq & vbCrLf & "Optional: " & _
  vbCrLf & objAttendeeOpt & vbCrLf & "NOTES " & vbCrLf & strNotes
  
 strCount = "Accepted: " & ia & vbCrLf & _
  "Declined: " & ide & vbCrLf & _
  "Tentative: " & it & vbCrLf & _
  "No response: " & ino
    
Set ListAttendees = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  ListAttendees.Body = strCopyData & vbCrLf & strCount
  ListAttendees.Display
   
EndClean:
Set objApp = Nothing
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objAttendees = Nothing
End Sub
```

Source [Create a List of Meeting Attendees and Responses](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/list-meeting-attendees-responses/)

---

#### Copying the attendee list with responses

> Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013 do allow you to copy the attendee information for direct usage in another application. To copy the information, open the meeting, expand the Tracking button and choose "Copy Status to Clipboard". You can now paste the attendee list in another application.
>
> [image: Copy meeting attendee list in Outlook 2010]
>
> You can copy the attendee responses in Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013 and paste it in another application.
>
> Note 1: The copied list is tab-delimited and might not be suitable for usage directly in Word. If you paste it in Excel first, then copy from Excel and paste in Word you’ll end up with a table which you can easily format in Word.
>
> Note 2: If you want to update the responses so they will reflect whether they actually showed up or not see [Manual meeting responds tracking](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/351)

Source [Print or copy the meeting attendee list](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/499)

---

#### Printing the attendee list with responses

> Outlook itself does not include the responses of the attendees when printing the meeting. A workaround would be to use the copy method as described above and print it from the application that you pasted the image or list in.
>
> This above workaround might not be practical if you need to do this a lot and a screenshot image might look quite out of place when used in a professional meeting report.
>
> A more streamlined solution can be achieved when using an add-in called [Attendees Print from IMIBO](http://addins.howto-outlook.com/imibo_attendeesprint). With this add-in you can…
>
> ```
> - print directly the names of the people who have been invited to a meeting.
> - print directly response status – Accepted, Declined, Tentative, None
> - save/export report directly to Microsoft® Office Word
> - save/export report directly to Microsoft® Office Excel
> - save/export report as RTF file
> - save/export report as Adobe PDF file
> - save/export report as HTML file
> ```
>
> [image]

Note the add-in is available as trial software and a license must be purchased.

Source [Print or copy the meeting attendee list](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/499)